# Transpose list to rows of data

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, delimited

I've data in a file like this:

```
196465702|91017022|['95592022', '96094942', '100920382']|91048702
```

and I will be transforming the data as below:

```
196465702|91017022|95592022|91048702
196465702|91017022|96094942|91048702
196465702|91017022|100920382|91048702
```

So far i've attempted to write this. Not sure if this is an accurate and optimal way. Moreover, If there is a list in 4th column and 5th column etc, it becomes tricky to loop for every column and join back.

```
import csv
with open('sample.out','r') as x:
  f = csv.reader(x,delimiter='|')
  for row in f:
    s = row[2].translate(None,"'")
    #print s.split(',')
    for t in s.split(','):
      print row[0]+'|'+row[1]+'|'+t.translate(None,"[None]")+'|'+row[3].translate(None,"None")
```

Is there any better way to write this? Additionally, if data has List in few columns, is there any better way to identify and transpose to rows and join back with rest of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done it like this

```
data = "196465702|91017022|['95592022', '96094942', '100920382']|91048702"
from ast import literal_eval
first, second, third, last = data.split("|")
third = literal_eval(third)
for item in third:
    print "{}|{}|{}|{}".format(first, second, item, last)
```

**Output**

```
196465702|91017022|95592022|91048702
196465702|91017022|96094942|91048702
196465702|91017022|100920382|91048702
```

Comment: Thanks for literal_eval. its quite intuitive and far more compact. Additionally if I were to add couple of more columns that has list values, is this good?
`x="196465702|91017022|['95592022', '96094942', '100920382']|91048702|['x','y']"
from ast import literal_eval
a, b, c, d,e = x.split("|")
c = literal_eval(c)
e = literal_eval(e)
for cc in c:
  for ee in e:
    print "{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(a,b,cc,d,ee)`

Comment: One related question: what if `data` is a list. 
`a,b,c,d = t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3]
c = literal_eval(c)`
This is going to fail to parse

Comment: @user3327034 Can you show a sample of `data` when it is a list?

Comment: Here is the original data. I've initially transformed to a pipe delimited data. `['197056942', '91004902', ['104608942', '95134582'], '91967062']`

Comment: @user3327034 Here the `data` is already in the Python processable list, so you can simply skip the `literal_eval` step